# Calculating speed of minute hand on a clock

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, dimensional-analysis

> The minute hand on a clock is $12 \text{ cm}$ long. Calculate the speed of its free end.

Is the following correct ? I have already worked out its angular speed from the previous question.

$$v = \omega r \\
\omega = 1.75\times 10^{-3} \text{ rad s$^{-1}$} \\
r = 12\text{ cm} = 1200\text{ m}$$

$$\begin{align}\therefore v &= (1.75\times 10^{-3} \text{ rad s$^{-1}$})\times (1200\text{ m}) \\
\therefore v &= 2.1\text{ ms$^{-1}$}\end{align}$$

Comment: $12 \text{ cm} = 0.12 \text{ m} \ne 1200 \text{ m}$.

Comment: I would go back to the previous question and check your angular speed, too.

Comment: @DougM why should I go back ? Is the answer for angular speed incorrect ? Thanks.

Comment: @Dan No.  Your angular speed is correct.

Comment: Okay thanks @Bye_World

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12 cm = 0.12 m, not 1200 m ,,,,,,,

Comment: He said the $\omega$ came from the previous question.

Comment: @tilper:  I just saw that

Comment: So should the final answer be 2.1 x 10^-4 ms^-1 ? Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1):

The tip travels $2\pi\cdot12$ cm in one hour, hence $2\pi\cdot12/3600$ cm/s. (About $0.21$ mm/s.)

Comment: So should the final answer be 2.1 x 10^-4 ms^-1 ? Is this correct ?

Comment: @Dan: possibly.

Answer (score 0):

The angular speed of the minute hand of a clock is $\dfrac{2\pi}{3600} rad/s$ or $\dfrac{\pi}{1800} rad/s$.